# Using new symbol in WhenEvent in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

This is an example in Mathematica's help document.

```
NDSolve[{y''[t] == -9.81, y[0] == 5, y'[0] == 0,  
   WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> -0.95 y'[t]]}, y, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[y[t] /. %, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I do a modification like this:

```
NDSolve[{y''[t] == -9.81, y[0] == 5, y'[0] == 0, a = y[t]; b=y'[t];
   WhenEvent[a == 0, b -> -0.95 b]}, y, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[y[t] /. %, {t, 0, 10}]
```

It doesn't work.

If I want to keep a new symbol just as here `a` to represent the `y[t]` or some expression about `y[t]` in the `WhenEvent`, what can I do to achieve this goal?

(The error may be caused by the `HoldAll` attribute of `WhenEvent`.
Why I want to replace the `y[t]` by `a`?
It is important to me. Bucause I will use a dynamic `a` in the WhenEvent )

Comment: If you want to update `a` why not use a `ParametricNDSolve`? It might be good, if could show what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what you are looking for, how about using a function:

```
test[a_?NumericQ] := a + 1
NDSolve[{y''[t] == -9.81, y[0] == 5, y'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[test[y[t]] == 0, y'[t] -> -0.95 y'[t]]}, y, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[y[t] /. %, {t, 0, 10}]
```